Xcode failing to show correct launch image with multiple .xcassets in project
I manage several white-labelled React Native apps that share a common codebase but differ in branding details: splash screen, icon, and startup pre-configuration (we use react-native-config for this). This question is specifically about iOS and Xcode; I don't believe RN is related (but mention it for completeness).
I use Xcodegen to generate the project, with multiple targets and build schemes, and use Cocoapods for dependency management.
Each version of the app has a separate Info.plist, launch screen .storyboard, and .xcassets containing the app icon and image used on the launch screen. Xcodegen is setting targets correctly for the storyboard and xcassets catalogue. Each asset catalogue has two uniformly named assets: icon and launch.
Despite having the asset catalogue and storyboard targeted correctly for each app, the storyboards insist on displaying the wrong launch image.  This is consistent across all apps: it's the same image every time. The image is from one of the asset catalogues, but (except the one correct case) the wrong catalogue.
I've cleaned, cleared derived data, rebuilt the project completely via Xcodegen, deleted any stray build folders, and tried switching build schemes, all without avail.  The (incorrect) launch image is the only one that shows up in the image properties source dropdown.
While this isn't fatal, and the apps build correctly, and display icon and splash images correctly when they launch, it's annoying, and doesn't allow accurate fine-tuning of launch screens.
Is there anything else I should try to get Xcode to see and use the correct images from the appropriate .xcassets when editing an app's launch storyboard?
I'm using Xcode 15.2 on an M3 MBP running Sonoma.

launch image is relatively new feature... can you create a copy of launch image and name it uniquely?

Thanks for the comment.  This is my fallback position, and it works, but I wanted  to understand if it's me, or Xcode, or some other subtlety that's preventing what seems like a valid use of asset catalogues, namely identically named assets in catalogues that have different targets).

That's a good question. When I had read the official docs (a while ago), I don't think they were clear on the how this works.
